# How to send 2 different object in postman by method post with Spring boot?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm writing a function in controller which should add an object 'Post' into a property of another object 'Topic' which is an arraylist. The parameters required for this function is a 'Post'(p) and the id (topicID) of 'Topic'. I want to know how to send them in Postman.

When I try to send them by filling all parameters of the 'Post' + topicID of 'Topic' in Postman, I got an error message as below.

The function in controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/TopicController")
public class TopicController {
    @Autowired
    TopicRepository topicRepository;
    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/AddPost")
    public void addPost(Post p, @RequestParam(value="topicID") int topicID) {
        if (topicRepository.existsById(topicID)) {
            Optional<Topic> ot = topicRepository.findById(topicID);
            Topic t = ot.get();
            t.addPost(p);
            p.setTopic(t.getName());
            postRepository.save(p);
            topicRepository.save(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Class Post :

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String topic;
    private String title;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date posteDate;
    private String auther;
    @Lob
    private String content;
    private int readTimes;

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }
}
```

Class Topic :

```
@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;
    @Lob
    private String presentation;

    private ArrayList<String> coverPhotos;
    private ArrayList<Post> posts;

    public void addPost(Post post) {
        this.posts.add(post);
    }

    public void setPosts(ArrayList<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

}
```

Error message:

```
2019-05-07 11:56:22.907 ERROR 24900 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the array before using .add(), change your addPost() like this:

```
public void addPost(Post post) {
    if(posts == null) posts = new ArrayList<>();
    this.posts.add(post);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@RequestBody` annotation in your controller method.
Your controller method should look something like below, this way the body will be mapped to your `Post` object and the query parameter `topicId` will be mapped to your `topicId` object.

```
public void addPost(@RequestBody Post p, @RequestParam(value="topicID") int topicID)
```